# Google Colab: GPU not accessible when using different python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpu, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

For one third-party library, I need python 3.8. So installed it using these commands,

```bash
!sudo apt-get update
!sudo apt install python3.8
!sudo apt install python3-pip
!sudo apt install python3.8-distutils
```

installed tensorflow,

```bash
!python3.8 -m pip install tensorflow
```

Now, when I run this command in a cell, it does not list GPU.

```bash
!python3.8 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

Output:

```
2024-02-27 20:24:15.750607: I tensorflow/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:28] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-02-27 20:24:15.753880: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-02-27 20:24:17.568337: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-02-27 20:24:19.784763: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:995] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-02-27 20:24:20.356554: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1960] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
```

But, when I run the same code using default python version, it does list available GPU.

```bash
!python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

Output:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

I have setup [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yV0mwSiO8A4V7kuRZQqfWvUUJ2yGero4?usp=sharing) notebook as example.

What's wrong?